# Jquery datetimepicker problem

Tags: jquery

```
$('#brandTimeStamp').datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss' 
});
```

`datetimepicker()` jQuery is not working properly in Firefox.

Whenever I try to change the value of date then it adds 100 years to date.

This code is working fine in IE.

Please suggest solution to this problem.

Comment: Please put your code in code blocks. Any other details other than that? If you want us to help, we need more information than one line of code and "please help me". Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

As I believe it, the date format in javascript doesn't require `yyyy` for the year. To get a date as `11/07/2011` your date format will need to be `dd/mm/yy`

Comment: it`s not working in dateptimeicker to get yyyy format using "dd/mm/yy". dd/mm/yy works only in datepicker.

Comment: Ahh ok, I didn't know there was a difference. Sorry!